# using logical arrays to select certain elements into another matrix

Tags: matlab

I believe the answer to this is simple but my brain will not function.

Say I have a m x n matrix which is of type double & lets call it A. I also have a matrix B, which is m x n and is all NaN's.

I then want to find out which numbers are say equal to some number, let say 100. I can do the following,

```
  A_index = A == 100;
```

So I now have a logical array, A_index. This is all fine.

My question is how do I select the elements from A where A_index is true into matrix B?

Some made up matrices

```
A= [ 50 100 75 90 100; 0 50 60 30 10; 100 25 80 250 100; 5 100 0 100 90];
A_index = A == 100;
B= zeros(4,5) * NaN;
```

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I've just added some sample matrices

Comment: Since `A` and `B` are the same size and shape, try `B(A==100) = ...` (replacing the ... by whatever expression you want on the rhs).  Then read the documentation on the topic of *logical indexing*.

Comment: Here is a link to the SO documentation : [indexing in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/235/getting-started-with-matlab-language/2080/indexing-matrices-and-arrays#t=201611010835452212905).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
A= [ 50 100 75 90 100; 0 50 60 30 10; 100 25 80 250 100; 5 100 0 100 90];
A_index = A == 100;

B= zeros(4,5) * NaN;

B(A_index) = 100
```

This way you will get 100 in the entries of B where A is equal to 100

See the section on logical indexing in the MATLAB [docs](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)